# Multi-Step MFA Authentication

Tags: yodlee

I've noticed some institutions have a multi-step MFA, for example the first MFA question will be a "token style" request for a phone number, which after submitting, the user gets a text and needs to respond with a token.  How does one detect this situation and submit the final step to Yodlee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what Yodlee calls a "Multi level" MFA.  You can use DagMultilevel to test this.  When checking for an MFA request, this must be in a loop, such that you keep checking after each MFA response to see if "isMessageAvailable" is true.

Answer (score 0):

Along with "isMessageAvailable" you should be checking the error code too, if error code is not null then there is no more MFA present.

If error code is 0 then the request was successful or else it failed with an error.
You can check for those error codes in this page https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes